# More efficient way? other than using for loop with np.trapz() to generate an integral curve over large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, integral

I have a large pandas Data Frame of around 210711 rows.

Currently I am using for loop for generating integral of particular column and plotly for plotting the data.

Following is the code used:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

DF = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\hsr4ban\Desktop\Temp\Temp.csv")

DF_01 = DF[["timestamps", "Data01", "Data02"]]

Integral_List = []

for ind in range(len(DF_01)):
    Integral = np.trapz(y = DF_01.loc[:ind, "Data02"], x = DF_01.loc[:ind, "timestamps"])
    Integral_List.append(Integral)

DF_01["Integral"] = Integral_List

Fig = make_subplots(rows = 2,
                    cols = 1,
                    shared_xaxes = True)

Fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = DF_01["timestamps"],
                         y = DF_01["Data02"],
                         name = "Data",
                         mode = "lines"),
              row = 1, col = 1)

Fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = DF_01["timestamps"],
                         y = DF_01["Integral"],
                         name = "Integral",
                         mode = "lines"),
                row = 2, col = 1)

Fig.show()
```

When above code is run, I get following graph as output:
[image]

However, when for loop is used for generating "Integral" column, it is consuming lots of time.
Is there any efficient way to do this? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Get the `y` and `x` inputs to `trapz` as arrays before running the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the loop with [`scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid.html).

```
from scipy.integrate import cumulative_trapezoid
DF_01["Integral"] = cumulative_trapezoid(y=DF_01["Data02"], 
                                         x=DF_01["timestamps"],
                                         initial=0)
```